# System.ExecutionEngineException with DLLImport in VB.Net

Tags: .net, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm currently attempting to update a vb6 32 bit COM wrapper to .Net (to eventually call out of process from a 64 bit application). The following code appears to work up to the point that I assign values to _dSpeedOfSound, ie, gOutput is populated with 3 return values. However, when I attempt to access the property dSpeedOfSound (or any of the three) I receive the following error: "Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown". This is true even if I break in immediately after _dSpeedOfSound is set and try ?dSpeedofSound from the immediate window. I assume I'm missing at least one important step but I'm new to COM and not sure how to continue from here. Suspect I'm not handling the arrays properly. Any help appreciated, relevant code below:

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
<Guid("C3516C29-5A8C-4D09-8869-6DAF597EC123")> _
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)> _
Public Interface INF_AGA8

    Sub NF_AGA8()   
    ...
    Readonly Property dSpeedOfSound() As Double
    ...
End Interface

ComVisible(True)> _
<Guid("04385623-B6F2-44CF-AD82-C1FEE5EACB42")> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
<ProgId("NFLOMIC.NF_AGA8")> _
Public Class NF_AGA8
  Implements INF_AGA8
    ...
    Private _dSpeedOfSound As Double
    ...
    Public ReadOnly Property dSpeedOfSound() As Double Implements INF_AGA8.dSpeedOfSound
        Get
            Return _dSpeedOfSound
        End Get
    End Property
    ...
    Private gInput(0 To 11) As Double
    Private gOutput(0 To 2) As Double
    ...
    <DllImport("C:\temp\TSS DLL\aga8.dll)> _
    Public Shared Function aga8_g(ByRef ain As Double, ByRef aout As Double, ByRef iErrCode As Integer, 
    ByRef sErrMess As String, ByRef iEFlags As Long) As Integer
    End Function
    ...
    Call aga8_g(gInput(0), gOutput(0), iErrCode, sLomicErrMessage, iErrFlags)
        _dMolarDensity = gOutput(0)
        _dCompressibility = gOutput(1)
        _dSpeedOfSound = gOutput(2)
    ...
```

The following is from the working vb6 code (using option base 1):

```
Private Declare Sub aga8_g Lib "d:\psoft\lomic\bin\aga8.dll" (ain1 As Any, aout1 As Any, iErrCode As Integer, sErrMess As String, iEFlags As Long) 
...
Call aga8_g(aInput(1), aOutput(1), iErrCode, sLomicErrMessage, iErrFlags)
```

Comment: The aga8_g() declaration is completely wrong and the native code in aga8.dll is very likely to destroy the GC heap through "aout".  What the declaration *should* be is very hard to guess, As Any is too vague.  You need to post the C declaration to get somewhere here.  Contact the DLL owner for support.

Comment: Would have posted the C if I had it. All we have is a dll from a vendor who is now out of business and the prior vb6 declaration. I'm sure you're right about the GC heap but in what way is the aga8_g() declaration "completely" wrong?

Comment: Everything looks wrong.  ain and aout are probably arrays that need to be passed ByVal.  iErrCode must be Short.  sErrMess must be a StringBuilder passed ByVal.  iEFlags must be Integer.  There is no return value, use Sub.  I guess.

Comment: You have no documentation for this dll and the vendor is out of business?  You might want to consider alternatives (vendors, libraries, etc.)  Writing new code for a library from a non-existent vendor does not make good business sense.